# Trying to use IPTABLES to solve a problem

Tags: iptables, nat

I have one box running CentOS which is externally facing.  Inside the network I have another box running Ubuntu with Apache.  I want to be able to access web pages from outside the network which are located on the Ubuntu box.  I was told IPTABLES would allow for me to specify the IP Address of my CentOS box and the requests would be forwarded to the Ubuntu box.

I tried following a few tutorials but no dice.  Can anyone provide me with the commands to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On the router:

```
iptables -t -A PREROUTING -d <public address> -t tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to <internal address>:80
```

This assumes that the CentOS box *is* running as the default router for the network that the Ubuntu box is on, and that you just want to forward HTTP traffic on the default port.

Comment: If the CentOS box is sitting behind a router this won't work?  Why is that?

Comment: Every computer is "behind" a lot of routers.  Please re-read what I wrote.

Comment: You said "assumes that the CentOS box is running as the default router". I'm asking why it wouldn't work if it isn't the default router....

Comment: That's a different question, and questions go in questions, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use DNAT, as womble said:

```
iptables -t -A PREROUTING -d <public address> -t tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to <internal address>:80
```

but you have to enable ip_forwarding too, and set a minimum of firewall rules

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```